# Eclipse makes window explorer go slow

Tags: eclipse

I started using eclipse today. I downloades from the page, this version Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers, and suddenly, after using eclipse windows explorer starts going slow, it takes like 5 minutes to load a folder, and even if i close eclispe this problem is still there. I can't uninstall and reinstall because it was a zip archive not an executable. If i restart the computer, everything goes perfect, but afer i open eclipse one i can't even make right click on the desktop to creat a file, because it gets stuck.

No idea how to solve it. Any tips?

Comment: Windows Defender significantly slows down Eclipse (see [note here](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.25/)), but not that much. Maybe another anti-virus/security tool. What does the Task Manager show? I do not see this with _Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers_ 2022-09 on Windows 10.

Comment: No antivirus or antimalware software. When i go to the task manager with eclipse opened, it's taking a 40% of memory and a 1 % of procesor. The values are not even at 50% so i don't know why it's slowing that bad. I'm using this eclipse version https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2022-09/r/eclipse-ide-enterprise-java-and-web-developers.

Comment: Look into the Windows Task Manager for processes with high disk usage. Maybe there are some synchronizing/backup tools (when starting Eclipse installed from a ZIP archive, files are written in the `configuration` and `p2` subfolders plus workspace `.metadata` folder). Do you have Windows 10 or 11? In which directory did you unpack the ZIP archive?

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why but when i used eclipse something called microsoft one drive suddenly pop up and started taking 20% of the disk. Once i closed it it's going perfectly again.

Comment: Sound like your Eclipse installation directory or workspace directory is synchronized by Microsoft One Drive.

Comment: Yeah but it really takes a lot of space. Even when i'm coding or playing usually i never get to use a lot of the disk so it was really weird that something as basic as Microsoft One Drive took that much space